# Reading multiple page PDF file using Google Cloud Vision

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am currently trying to read a multiple page pdf file using the google cloud vison API. I am currently only able to read the first page of the pdf and I am also getting an error in my code that gives me an error in my one line of code. I have attached pieces of my code below. How can I solve this error, and also be able to read the whole pdf instead of just one page?
[image: Piece of code]

[image: Error I am receiving]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Vision API JSON responses in your GCS are correct, you need to get the whole response instead of getting only the 1st element in `response['responses']` and loop through it to get the annotation per page. See code below:

```
blob_list = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))
print('Output files:')
for obj in blob_list:
    print(obj.name)

for blob in blob_list[1:]:

    json_string = blob.download_as_string()
    response = json.loads(json_string)

    pages_response = response['responses'] #get complete response
    for page in pages_response: #loop through all pages
        annotation = page['fullTextAnnotation']

        print('Full text:\n')
        print(annotation['text'])
        print('END OF PAGE')
        print('##########################')
```

I used a Google Vision sample file (gs://cloud-samples-data/vision/document_understanding/custom_0773375000.pdf) and processed 3 pages. See sample run:

[image]